# WHERE varchar = variable length of 0's

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Table_A

ID    Number
--    ------
1     0
2     00
3     0123
4     000000
5     01240
6     000
```

The 'Number' column is data type varchar.

**EDIT for clarity.**
My question is, can I easily pull back all rows of data which contain a variable length string of 0's?

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE LEFT(Number,1) = '0' AND RIGHT(Number,1) = '0'
```

Using the above, it would still return the below, using the example table provided.

```
ID    Number
--    ------
1     0
2     00
4     000000
5     01240
6     000
```

I was looking for a function which I could pass the `LEN(Number)` int into, and then it generates a string of a specfic character (in my case a string of 0's). I wasn't able to find anything though.

Oh, and I also tried adding a `SUBSTRING` to the `WHERE` clause, but sometimes the `Number` column has a number which has a 0's in the middle, so it still returned strings with other numbers except only 0.

`SUBSTRING(Number,ROUND(LEN(Number)/2,0),1) = '0'`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear, you *want* to match rows 1, 2, 4 and 6, and not to match rows 3 and 5, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you want a string that *doesn't* contain anything that *isn't* a `0`? Sounds like it's time for a double-negative:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A
WHERE NOT Number like '%[^0]%'
AND number like '0%' --But we do want it to contain at least one zero
```

(The final check is so that we don't match the empty string)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain, or provide a link , to how the `'%[^0]%'` part works?

Comment: @lturner - that says, "match any string that contains any number of characters, then a character that *isn't* a 0, than any number of other characters". The only strings that don't match that condition are strings that only contain `0`s.

Comment: Okay great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

```
Where number like '%0%'
```

Comment: This will not work because using the wildcards allows the string to return other characters, not just a variable length string of 0's.

Comment: I just answering your question: *'My question is, can I easily pull back all rows of data which contain one or more '0'?'*

Comment: Your solution will pull back strings which contain characters other than '0' though.

Comment: My answer catch your requirements. But, if you are looking for rows with only 0s then: `where '00000000000000' like number + '%'`;

Comment: I updated my question for clarity on what I'm asking. Thanks for your help though, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE len(Number) - len(replace(number,'0','')) >= 0
```

One more approach

Comment: should be `where len(replace(number,'0',''))  = 0 and len(number) > 0`

Comment: @fuzzytree..modified it to get strings where all characters are `0`s.does it still  need a change?

Answer (score 0):

Your can use this query :

SELECT * FROM Table_A WHERE Number LIKE '%0%';

It'll solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following one also,you will get your expected result.

SELECT *

FROM Table_A

WHERE  Nunber not like '%[1-9]%'

Thanks.